# Why does the every two rows end up in the same cell?

Tags: c++, csv, cell, ofstream

I have been coming here for many years and I have always found previous questions a or topic that would help me out, but today I can't seem to find the answer to my problem, so I wrote my first question.

I have a .csv document with the following layout.

**CELL A1:** Title1,Title2,Title3,...
**CELL A2:** Date1,Name1,Data11,Data12,Data13,...
**CELL A3:** Date2,Name2,Data21,Data22,Data23,...

I need to extract a specific set of columns as well as rows with specific Name (not yet included in presented code).

The problem is the outputed lines of text write themselves in pair in the first cell while they should all have their own row. I tried writing in a .txt files and no problem were found. Looks like this :
Row 1: A: Title1 B: Title2 C: Title3 ...
Row 2: A: Date1,Name1,Data11,Data12,Data13,Date2 B: Name2 C: Data21 D: Data22...

My csv use the semicolon (";") as separator.

This is the code so far (I tried to reomove as much useless content):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main(){
//Name of the rooms to be extracted
char *row2keep[] = {"Name1","Name2"};
//Number of the rows to be extracted
int col2keep[] = {1,2,3,4,5};
ifstream  data("Nameoffile.csv");

string  line;
string  cell;
int     col = 0;
int     row = 0;
ofstream outdata;
outdata.open("sorting.csv", ios::app);

while(getline(data,line)){
    col = 0;
    row ++;
    stringstream  lineStream(line);
    while(getline(lineStream,cell,',')){
        col ++;
        for(int c = 0; c < 5; ++c){
            if(col2keep[c] == col){
                replace(cell.begin(),cell.end(),'.',',');
                cout << cell << ";";
                outdata << cell << ";";
            }
        }
    }
    cout << "\n";
    outdata << "\n";
}
data.close();
outdata.close();
return 0;
}
```

The problem seems to be that the for() loop in the final while() loop messes with the ofstream in some way because when I remove it, all eight lines end up one after another in different rowswithout a problem.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please include the relevant information as text in the question itself, not as links to images. Please see [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: It seems your array `col2keep` contains 5 column numbers, but your loop `for(int c = 0; c < 6; ++c)` goes from 0 to 5 (that are 6 elements), which is out of bounds and undefined behavior so who knows what happens. Or am I missing something here?

Comment: Also why do you have a while loop with 1 iteration for the header line? that confused me, a simple if would also do and no need for the break. :)

Comment: @Marc Thank you for the insight. I modified my question to better suit the guidelines.

Comment: @xander It used to have 6 elements and it seems I forgot to reduce those boundaries. I changed it, but the problem still persist. For the first iteration, I wanted to do manipulation to the headers that caused problem to the rest of the loop. I have merged them now.

Comment: It seems that by adding a space before every cell and removing it afterwards with the remove function did the trick. 

     outdata << "";
     remove(cell.begin(),cell.end(),'"');

I am trying to figure out a way to now only write the required rows from a predetermined list.

     char *list[] = {n elements};

Comment: I tried find, strstr but I can't even get it to compile. How should it be scripted?